# Drop events are not firing in AngularDart app however Drag events are firing

Tags: dart, angular-dart

my first post on SO!

In short, I'm researching Dart drag & drop libraries for use in an AngularDart project. I have created an example repo (https://bitbucket.org/johnryanancoa/componentdecorator/src/). The  tag produces the desired markup, onto which a decorator attaches the relevant events. The Drag events are correctly printing    a message to the console when an event fires. However, the Drop events are not firing.

Can anyone shed any light on this please? I'm thinking I'm making mistakes with my use of Futures although would appreciate any pointers.

Thank you in advance. John

UPDATE: adding relevant code snippets from the above repo as per @slawson's suggestion

== main.html ==

```dart
<body>
    <my-component class="my-component" my-decorator></my-component>
    ...
</body>
```

== main.dart ==

```dart
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';

import 'package:componentDecorator/component/component.dart';
import 'package:componentDecorator/component/decorator.dart';

String _delimiter = "-";

class MyMod extends Module {
    final Logger log = new Logger('componentDecorator');

    MyMod() {
        bind(MyCoolDecorator);
        bind(MyCoolComponent);
    }
}

void main() {
    Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
    Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
        print('[${rec.level.name}: ${rec.loggerName}] ${_delimiter} ${rec.message}');
    });

    applicationFactory()
            .addModule(new MyMod())
            .run();
}
```

== component.dart ==

```dart
library mycomponent;

import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'packages/componentDecorator/component/component.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/componentDecorator/component/component.css',
    publishAs: 'comp'
) class MyCoolComponent {

    MyCoolComponent(final Element element) {
        Logger.root.fine("MyCoolComponent(): element = $element, element.attributes = ${element.attributes.keys}");
    }
}
```

== component.html ==

```dart
<ul dnd dnd-dropzone>
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>one</li>
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>three</li>
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>five</li>
</ul>

<ul dnd dnd-dropzone class="even">
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>two</li>
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>four</li>
    <li dnd dnd-draggable>six</li>
</ul>
```

== decorator.dart ==

```dart
library mydecorator;

import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

import 'package:componentDecorator/dnd/dnd.dart';

@Decorator(
    selector: '[my-decorator]'
) class MyCoolDecorator extends AttachAware {

    final Element element;

    MyCoolDecorator(this.element);

    void attach() {
        new Future(() {
            var _el;
            if (element.shadowRoot != null) {
                _el = element.shadowRoot;
            } else {
                _el = element;
            }

            // common
            print("${_el.hashCode} el: ${_el}");

            print("${_el.hashCode} el.draggable: ${_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-draggable]').length}");
            Draggable draggable = new Draggable(_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-draggable]'), avatarHandler: new AvatarHandler.clone())
                    ..onDragStart.listen(onDragStart)
                    ..onDragEnd.listen(onDragEnd)
            ;
            print("${_el.hashCode} draggable: ${draggable}");

            print("${_el.hashCode} el.dropzones: ${_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-dropzone]').length}");
            Dropzone dropzones = new Dropzone(_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-dropzone]'), acceptor: new Acceptor.draggables([draggable]))
                    ..onDragEnter.listen(onDragEnter)
                    ..onDragLeave.listen(onDragLeave)
                    ..onDragOver.listen(onDragOver)
                    ..onDrop.listen(onDrop)
            ;
            print("${_el.hashCode} dropzones: ${dropzones}");
        });
    }

    Element getElement() {
        var _el;
        if (element.shadowRoot != null) {
            _el = element.shadowRoot;
        } else {
            _el = element;
        }

        // common
        print("${_el.hashCode} el: ${_el}");
        print("${_el.hashCode} el.dropzones: ${_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-dropzone]').length}");
        print("${_el.hashCode} el.draggable: ${_el.querySelectorAll('[dnd-draggable]').length}");
        return _el;
    }

    void onDragEnter(DropzoneEvent event) {
        print("onDragEnter()");
    }

    void onDragStart(DraggableEvent event) {
        print("onDragStart()");
    }

    void onDragEnd(DraggableEvent event) {
        print("onDragEnd()");
    }

    void onDragOver(DropzoneEvent event) {
        print("onDragOver()");
    }

    void onDrop(DropzoneEvent event) {
        print("onDrop()");
    }

    void onDragLeave(DropzoneEvent event) {
        print("onDragLeave()");
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the relevant code with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE!! Modifying the @Component declaration appears to resolve the issue...

Before

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'packages/componentDecorator/component/component.html',
    cssUrl: 'packages/componentDecorator/component/component.css',
    publishAs: 'comp'
) class MyCoolComponent {
```

After

```
@Component(
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: 'packages/componentDecorator/component/component.html',
    useShadowDom: false,
    publishAs: 'comp'
) class MyCoolComponent {
```

I need to investigate further tomorrow but at least it triggers the events and prints to the console! Thanks for your help nonetheless...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the 'correct' solution, but it is working for my scenario hence marking as the answer. Feel free to comment if/when other solutions become available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `preventDefault` on some drag-n-drop events (dragover) to indicate you will handle the drop event.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm using the "Dart Drag And Drop" library (http://goo.gl/0AnrCh) so at this early stage am not wanting to dive into the inner workings of the library to make modifications without fully understanding what I'm doing. Other preliminary tests have also suggested that the issue lies with the DOM elements not being aware of the onDrop event ONLY when they are injected into the view as the result of rendering the Component. My [albeit] limited understanding suggests that the relevant listeners are not being bound to the elements. Any thoughts...? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must send an `event.preventDefault()` in your `onDrag()` handler, or else your drag event will prevent your drop event from firing properly.

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    template: `
      <div
        (dragover)="onDragOver($event)"
        (drop)="onDrop($event)"
      >
        Drop here
      </div>
    `
});

export class MyComponent {
    void onDragOver(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // this allows onDrop() to fire later
        print("onDragOver()");
    }

    void onDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        print("onDrop()");
    }
}
```